# How to add delimited by a line break (CRLF) in bq extract command

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Generated the CSV file from the table using before bq extract command in bash file

```
C_date=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
bq extract --print_header=false --field_delimiter=',' 'dataset.table_name' gs://$BUCKET/<folder>/"test"$C_date".csv"
```

Result
[image]

But expected CRLF linebreak format in csv
[image]

Kindly help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's/\r\n|\n|\r/\r\n/g' original.csv > new.csv
```

This resolve the issue